# Updating a QGraphicsTextItem on text change

Tags: qt, qtruby, qgraphicstextitem

I’ve been working with `QGraphicsTextItem`. I currently have the laid out in a scene, each depicting a physical page of text. Right now I’m overriding the `keyReleaseEvent` function to redistribute the text typed across all of the pages. The problem with this is that when I set the text with `setPlainText`, the cursor moves back to the beginning of the `textitem` that is set as the focus item for the scene.

As you can imagine, this is problematic when typing, especially on another page instead of the one set to focus, it also makes the keyboard shortcuts for cutting and copying not work at all.

Is there a way to set the text of a `QGraphicsTextItem` without it resetting the cursor / moving the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

For your problem, there's one way I see you could fix it, but I'm not sure it's the best one. Here it is:

You can call `textCursor()` on your `QGraphicsTextItem` to get the `QTextCursor` of your `QGraphicsTextItem`. With this cursor, you can have its position by calling `position()`. Then keep this value, update the text and then set the position of the cursor by creating a new `QTextCursor`, setting his position with `setPosition(int pos, MoveMode m = MoveAnchor)`.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT** to add example:

```
// graphicsTextItem is of type QGraphicsTextItem*

QTextCursor cursor = graphicsTextItem->textCursor;
int startPosition = cursor.position();

// Do all you need to update your text.

QTextCursor afterCursor;
afterCursor.setPosition(startPosition);

graphicsTextItem->setTextCursor(afterCursor);
```

I have not tested this, I wrote it the way I thought it was going to work.